# Javascipt non stackable level generator

Tags: javascript

My task was to create a function that returns the level of a user.

A user has a certain amount of XP. Each level is `level * 10 xp`

so for example

- level 1 would be 10 xp
- level 2 would be 20 xp
- level 3 would be 30 xp

and so on

however your XP doesn't stack

so if you have 30 XP you would fill the requirements for level 1 and 2 but you wouldn't achieve level 3.

I'd love to know if there was anything else I could have improved

```
function get_level(xp, level = 0) {
  if (xp == 0) return level

  if (level > 0) {
    var generated_xp = level * 10
  } else {
    var generated_xp = 10
  }
  var letover = xp - generated_xp
  if (letover == 0) return level
  if (letover < 0) return level
  if (letover > 0) return get_level(xp - generated_xp, level + 1)
}
```

Comment: *if you have 30 XP ... you wouldn't achieve level 3.*  => so level 3 is greater than 30 xp, not equal to or greater? Same with other levels also? level 1 is greater than 10 xp, level 2 is greater than 20 xp. Is this correct?

Comment: No so basically your XP wont stack 

for example you have 30 xp

to reach level 10 xp are deducted 

then following inorder to be at level 2 20 xp are deducted 

therefore youre at level 2

Comment: *level 3 would be 30 xp*   and   *if you have 30 XP ... you wouldn't achieve level 3*    => These statements seem to contradict each other.  Also, I don't understand "XP doesn't stack".   I must be misunderstanding the basic concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

```js
// I assume this is meant to be called with only one argument initially?
function get_level(xp, level = 0) {
  // This is redundant, the rest of the code will take care of it
  if (xp == 0) return level

  // So does it require 10 LP to get from level 0 to 1, then 10 again to get from 1 to 2? That seems odd.
  if (level > 0) {
    // Generated XP is a confusing variable name. Maybe name it something like "required_xp" or "xp_to_next_level"
    var generated_xp = level * 10
  } else {
    var generated_xp = 10
  }

  // typo: letover, should probably be left over. Again this variable name could be clearer
  var letover = xp - generated_xp
  if (letover == 0) return level
  if (letover < 0) return level
  if (letover > 0) return get_level(xp - generated_xp, level + 1)
}
```

If I fixed a few issues but left the structure in tact, you would get something like this:

```js
function get_level(xp, level=0) {
   // Reduce the complexity by removing this if statement
   let xp_to_next_level = Math.max(10, level*10);
   
   // Remove one arm from the condition
   if (xp > xp_to_next_level) {
       return get_level(xp - generated_xp, level + 1);
   } else {
       return level;
   }
}
```

However, I usually try to avoid recursion since I think it makes code hard to read, so I'd prefer something like this:

```js
function get_level(xp) { // can remove second argument now
   let level=0;
   while (xp > Math.max(level * 10, 10)) {
       level++;
   } 
   return level;
}
```

Or even shorter using the [formula of triangle numbers: `a*(a+1)/2`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=a*%28a%2B1%29%2F2%3Dy%2C+solve+for+a):

```
function get_level(xp) {
    if (xp<10) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + Math.floor((Math.sqrt(8*(xp-10)/10 + 1) - 1)/2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

I thank you for your help

Comment: `xp => Math.floor((5 + Math.floor((20 * xp - 195) ** .5)) / 10) || 0;`